# Using "kind of of"

Tags: possessives, informal-language

I made up this sentence myself:

> Episodes 1~3 are kind of of their own arc.

I mean episodes 1~3 of a show form their self contained story. But I am a little worry about the two of's used consecutively, is it allowed or appropriate?

Comment: I supose one can have two consecutive *ofs*, such as in *John is kind of of his own people.* But I would say that is a rare kind of thing. So grammatical, yes; "appropriate" as in "an example of clear writing", well that depends on the reader. Compare the consecutive *ises* in *The thing is is that I don't want to go the movie*. Grammatical, yes. Clear? May depend on the reader but in this case usually yes. If I read it twice. Advice: try to reword your statement, as the consecutive use of two *ofs* is rare and can be taken for a simple typo of *1~3 are kind of their own arc*.

Comment: The example of  *The thing is is...* doesn't seem grammatical to me. The thing is THAT, not IS THAT.

Comment: **are kind of of** can be reduced to **have**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it "allowed"?  Well, there is no "Academy of the English Language" to tell you it's forbidden!  In English the only thing we can say is that something is generally correct according to standard usage or not.  **It's technically OK**, because "kind of" and "of their own arc" are separate phrases, and it's only by accident that "of of" occurs.

Is it "appropriate" - That's a judgement question.  I understand what you mean by the sentence ("Episodes 1-3 belong, in a way, to their own arc") but personally I think it is **ugly, unclear, and not something I would ever recommend**.

As GoDucks points out, it looks like a typo for a single "of", and either the reader will do a [double-take](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20take) upon reading it or they'll probably [miss it entirely](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5924861/an-illusion-that-explains-why-typos-are-so-hard-to-catch).  Therefore, it is probably not a good idea.  **It would be clearer to reword it as something like "Episodes 1-3 belong, in a way, to their own arc."**  I'm also curious why you want to say the episodes are *of* their own arc, instead of saying they *are* their own arc; **the sentence would be perfectly good, and clearer, without the double *of*, as "Episodes 1-3 are kind of their own arc."**